# onClick event gets fired only on double click in chrome 78

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, anchor

My React class is rendering HTML. I have a simple onClick event on the anchor tag. It was working fine till the previous version of chrome i.e. 77. Chrome updated and simple onClick event of react.js stopped working. It works fine in firefox and edge.

**In chrome event gets fired on double click instead of single click.**
It happens only in the development environment. The same code in the prototype is working fine in chrome 78 also.

// tags

```
<div className="toggle-chart">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="table-icon" id="someID" onClick={this.showTable} ></a>
</div>
```

//function

```
showTable(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.target.id == "someID"){
        console.log('abc')
    this.setState({recordStatus: true});
    }
}
```

This function is binded in constructor of react class.

//CSS

```
.toggle-chart {
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:0px;
    display:none;
}
.show-table-view:hover > .toggle-chart {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

If I remove **display:none** from css, it works. But not working on hover.

Comment: are you sure you have to set href if you handle onclick manually?

Comment: Would you try to remove href attr?

Comment: I already did. no difference.

Comment: it looks like some details are missing here, are you able to provide reproducible example in codesandbox?

Comment: Hi Evgeny, it works well in the HTML prototype. The issue is in the development environment only. I have created example. https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-shannon-kp57t

Comment: Thanks, not sure I understand though, what do you mean by dev environment?

Comment: This is happening only when element is visible by hovering on parent. If I use opacity intsead of display, it works.